# localStorage access between two google app scripts deployed as web apps

Tags: javascript, browser, google-apps-script, local-storage

I am trying to handover a string from GAS_web_app_A to GAS_web_app_B. GAS_web_app_B gets launched from a button on GAS_web_app_A's UI.

As localStorage is supposed to be accessible across the same origin, I stored 'stuff' from GAS_web_app_A and tried to read it from GAS_web_app_B - in the same browser - chrome.

But GAS_web_app_B is not able to read this 'stuff' stored by GAS_web_app_A.

1) do all google app scripts that are deployed as a web apps get resolved by browser's localStorage as being from the same origin?

step 1 : launch GAS_web_app_A via its URL - https: //script.google.com/a/macros/XXXX.com/s//dev

step 2 : localStorage.setItem("stuff", stuff);

step 3 : launch GAS_web_app_B via its URL - https: //script.google.com/a/macros/XXXX.com/s//dev (from GAS_web_app_A)

step 4 : console.log( 'stuff is ' + localStorage.getItem("stuff") );

I always get null in step 4. ( I am able to retrieve 'stuff' from GAS_web_app_A even after a reload though... )

Is this supposed to work or am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolutely not supposed to work. it would be a huge security issue. look into passing url parameters to the 2nd script.

Comment: thanks, I had it working via url params, but I was loolking at something more secure but without oauth. Still for curiosity, would you know how the browser differentiated the two pages even though their domains are the same? Does it hash the entire URL?

Comment: debug it and you will see. its in an iframe among other things.